# Push notification in node js and react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, push-notification, react-fullstack

Hey i create a todo list with **react js** and **node js** i get date from client when wants add task.
now I want to remember the one that tasks the time is today.
Can you explain with the code?

Answer (score 0):

For example you can check this tutorial

https://www.section.io/engineering-education/push-notification-in-nodejs-using-service-worker/

P.S. first google search's result